# Disable database-templates within ExpressionEngine 2

Tags: templates, config

I'm working on EE2 theme and I can't find solution how to force EE use templates directly from the file system.

Generally I want to disable database templates while I'm working on theme, to get development quickly.

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be the [save templates as files](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/templates_as_files.html) feature. Once you've configured a template path you can save individual templates as files or you can sync all of your templates to file via the Templates > Synchronize Templates page.

Once you've done that any changes you make to the template files will take effect immediately, without you needing to manually sync them to the DB.

Comment: Thanks. Sync creates dir name 'default_site' inside base templates dir. is it possible to change saving/sync dir from 'default_site' to 'mytemplatename' ?

Comment: 'default_site' represents your site name as set in EE preferences or in config.php  You can change that name so something else, of course.  You should also be aware that even if you save templates as files, there needs to be a database record for each template.

Comment: Thank you, Yuri. How can I add all templates and template groups to the database?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking but you can fully re-sync the templates back to the DB via the Synchronize Templates page.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend setting the [save template as text files](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/templates_as_files.html) (as suggested by Dom) option in you config file. There is a good tutorial about putting your config file to better use [here](http://jamieonsoftware.com/journal/2011/4/6/getting-to-know-expressionengine-2s-config-file.html).

In a nutshell though it's this:

```
$config['save_tmpl_files'] = "y";
$config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = "/path/to/your/templates/";
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to add other template groups to the synchronization not only default* and _assets ?